# How to connect a MacOS client to Linux WireGuard Server

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, mac, wireguard

## Background

I cannot for the life of me get this to work. I have a local host machine running MacOS and utilizing the native Mac WireGuard application. I am trying to establish a connection to a remote linux host running Ubuntu Server. One question I have, is do I have to forward the port of my linux server to the router on that network? Also any tips in troubleshooting would be very helpful.

| Mac Client | Linux Remote Server |
| --- | --- |
| Public ip: yy.yy.yy.yy | Public ip: xx.xx.xx.xx |
| Private ip: 10.0.0.6 | Private ip: 192.168.1.188 |
| Public key: cccccccccccccc | Public key: bbbbbbbbbbbbbb |
| Private key: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | Private key: dddddddddddddddd |

## Client Conf

#### [Interface]

PrivateKey = aaaaaaaaaaaaa

ListenPort = 51820

Address = 10.10.1.2/24

#### [Peer]

PublicKey = bbbbbbbbbbbbbb

AllowedIPs = 10.10.1.1/32

Endpoint = xx.xx.xx.xx:51820

## Server Conf

#### [Interface]

Address = 10.10.1.1/24

SaveConfig = true

ListenPort = 51820

PrivateKey = dddddddddddd

#### [Peer]

PublicKey = cccccccccccc

AllowedIPs = 10.10.1.2/32

## Logs

| Mac Client |
| --- |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.379 [APP] startActivation: Entering (tunnel: jellybelly) |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.380 [APP] startActivation: Starting tunnel |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.385 [APP] startActivation: Success |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.390 [APP] Tunnel 'jellybelly' connection status changed to 'connecting' |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.473 [NET] App version: 1.0.15 (26) |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.474 [NET] Starting tunnel from the app |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.564 [NET] DNS64: mapped 173.73.185.15 to itself. |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.564 [NET] Attaching to interface |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.565 [NET] UAPI: Updating private key |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.565 [NET] UAPI: Updating listen port |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.565 [NET] UAPI: Removing all peers |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.565 [NET] peer(nAaA…PVgA) - UAPI: Created |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.565 [NET] peer(nAaA…PVgA) - UAPI: Updating endpoint |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.565 [NET] peer(nAaA…PVgA) - UAPI: Updating persistent keepalive interval |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.566 [NET] peer(nAaA…PVgA) - UAPI: Removing all allowedips |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.566 [NET] peer(nAaA…PVgA) - UAPI: Adding allowedip |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.566 [NET] Routine: encryption worker 2 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.566 [NET] UDP bind has been updated |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.566 [NET] peer(nAaA…PVgA) - Starting |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.566 [NET] Interface state was Down, requested Up, now Up |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.566 [NET] Device started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.566 [NET] Routine: event worker - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.567 [NET] Tunnel interface is utun3 |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.567 [NET] Network change detected with satisfied route and interface order [en3] |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.568 [APP] Tunnel 'jellybelly' connection status changed to 'connected' |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.569 [NET] Routine: handshake worker 3 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.569 [NET] Routine: decryption worker 2 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.569 [NET] Routine: encryption worker 4 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.569 [NET] Routine: decryption worker 4 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.572 [NET] Routine: handshake worker 2 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.572 [NET] Routine: encryption worker 3 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.573 [NET] Routine: encryption worker 1 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.573 [NET] Routine: decryption worker 1 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.573 [NET] Routine: handshake worker 1 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.575 [NET] Routine: decryption worker 3 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.575 [NET] peer(nAaA…PVgA) - Routine: sequential sender - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.575 [NET] Routine: handshake worker 4 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.575 [NET] Routine: TUN reader - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.575 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v6 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.576 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v4 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.576 [NET] peer(nAaA…PVgA) - Routine: sequential receiver - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.578 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v6 - stopped |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.579 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v4 - stopped |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.580 [NET] UDP bind has been updated |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.580 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v6 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:05.581 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v4 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:06.140 [NET] Network change detected with satisfied route and interface order [en3, utun3] |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:06.141 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v4 - stopped |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:06.141 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v6 - stopped |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:06.146 [NET] UDP bind has been updated |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:06.146 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v4 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:06.146 [NET] Routine: receive incoming v6 - started |
| 2022-01-12 11:48:10.385 [APP] Status update notification timeout for tunnel 'jellybelly'. Tunnel status is now 'connected'. |

Comment: Your log says it connected: "Tunnel status is now 'connected'."

Answer (score 0):

Change `AllowedIPs` value in client configuration to `0.0.0.0/0`.
Also you don't need `ListenPort` in client configuration.